# Why and how does a bad pivot choice make Quicksort O(n^2)?

Tags: pivot, quicksort

For example when the pivot is the highest or lowest value in the array.

For quicksort that uses 2 pointers, 1 goes Left end to right, the other goes right end to left, a pointer stops when it finds an element out of place in respect to the pivot, when both have stopped, they swap the elements and continue on from that position. But, why and how does a bad pivot choice make Quicksort O(n^2)?

Comment: You try this first and then come with real problem.

Comment: Try sorting sequence 1, 2, 3 ... n, choosing leftmost element as pivot in each partitioning. You will come up with the answer faster than you wrote this question I think.

Answer (score 5):

> how does a bad pivot choice make Quicksort O(n^2)?

Let's say you always pick the smallest element as your pivot. The top-level iteration of quicksort will require `n-1` comparisons and will split the array into two subarrays: one of size `1` and one of size `n-1`. The first one is already sorted, and you apply the quicksort recursively to the second one. Splitting the second one will require `n-2` comparisons. And so on.

In total, you have `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n * (n-1) / 2 = O(n^2)` comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

If your chosen pivot happened to be the maximal value in your subset on every recursion, the algorithm would simply move every record read into the subset below the pivot, and continue on with only one non-empty partition.  This new subset's size would be only one less.

In that case, the quicksorts operation would be similar to a selection sort.  I would find a maximal value, put it where it goes, and move on to the rest of the data in the next iteration.  The difference being that the selection sort searches for the maximal (or minimal) data point, where the worst-case quicksort would happen to select the maximal value and then discover that it is, indeed, the maximum.

This is a quite rare case, to my knowledge.

Comment: Not always rare if the input set is sorted, or nearly sorted, and a bad choice of pivot is made.

Answer (score 0):

Try a list with n times the same number.
Choose any way to find a privot.
Look whats happening.

(Edit: To make some hints:
The pivot does not depend on the way to find a pivot, because it is always the same.
So in every iteration, for the current list with n elements you will need n comparisons and you will split the list with n current elements in two sublists with 1 and n-1 elements.
You can quickly calculate the number of operations overall. You need `n, n-1, n-2, ..., 2, 1` operations.
Formally, it is the `sum from i=1 to n over i`, for which you should know a formula to see it is `O(n*n)`)

Comment: Why do you think you will end up with two sublists with 1 and n-1 elements? From intuition I'd end up with two sublists each having (n-1)/2 elements ... or maybe even 0 elements, depending on how you do the partitioning step.

Comment: @melpomene: Ok, this depends on the implementation. If elements are swapped in the case of equality, I agree with the half way. About maybe even 0: I do not know if I understand you correct, but if you have partitions with 0 and n (n>1) elements, you will have some problems in loop/recursion termination.

Comment: Suppose we partition the current subarray into 3 blocks: Elements less than the pivot, equal to the pivot, greater than the pivot. Then we'd recursively sort the smaller/greater blocks. If all elements are equal to the pivot, the two outer blocks have size 0 and we terminate immediately.

Comment: How do you get this partition? The typical quicksort does a swap. As far as I see you have to count the identical ones, move not identical ones and fill the mid after the final swap. This would have the same complexity class, but makes the algorithms a bit more complex. Do you have an easy way for this? (If we have this 3-partition, I would agree that equal elements do not care)